# Is it possible to set up a reminder in Outlook that will appear more than once per day?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, tasks

I'd like to set up a periodic reminder (say, once every two hours) to remind me to do stretches at my desk during the work day. Since I'm running Outlook (2010) all the time on my workstation, its tasks/reminders seem like an ideal candidate. But is there any way to set up a reminder that will go off more than once a day?

Answer (score 0):

I think not, but you could set one up every 2 hours and then use recurrence every day.